# In Shopify "Product page" is indexed with collection URL , Why?

Tags: indexing, seo, shopify, google-search-console

My product page (Shopify) URL is **abc.com/product/blue-shirt/** and it is in the "Shirt" collection. I have an issue about indexing, Like; Google indexing both URLs **abc.com/product/blue-shirt/** | **abc.com/collections/shirt/product/blue-shirt/**.

I don't know why, because I have submitted a sitemap with this format **abc.com/product/blue-shirt/**, Som other URLs shouldn't be indexed.

Hope you understand my point.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the product.url in your collections template or other templates where collection product links are used. You just need to remove "within: collection".

```
{{ product.url | within: collection }}
```

and replace with

```
{{ product.url }}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I already remove the "collection" from the product URL. That's why I'm confused about it, that why google indexing it with the collection name, even it does not exist.

Comment: If you already changed it, then you need to wait for the some days. Because google will take some time to update it. I think it will be updated after some days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think those indexed URLs are now removing from Google. By removing "within: collection" from code, google won't index it.